# Google wave authentication login on 3rd party website

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-wave

I'm trying to figure out how to make a user authenticate with my web app using google accounts and be recognized as an active session with google wave.

Currently when I use google accounts login, everything works fine, but the embedded google wave widgets dont recognize the user's session and asks him to re-login.

The only way I found around this is using friend connect, which is an open social login and lets you be recognized by the embedded wave automatically. However, it's a workaround and I would rather use a straight forward google account login process and not facebook connect like.

I saw there is a ?service=wave,gmail,calendar parameter when I init the login. Is there a way to make the same call with wave as a service to let the user authenticate with google wave too?